# Bootstrap 3 gridsize

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to figure out the new grid system in bootstrap 3 (I am new to Bootstrap in general).

In the [bootstrap tutorial](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) they state that the grid has 12 units but for `.col-xs` the sum often reaches 18 while others reach 12.

I cannot figure out why.

Comment: We'd need to see your code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the [grid options](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options), the grid always has 12 columns for any screen size. Keep in mind that you can have multiple column classes on one div, such as:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">stuff</div>
```

This will make this div 12 columns on extra small devices, and 8 columns wide on medium.

EDIT:

I think this example may have been what you were referring to ([here's its fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ringstaff/8ETrv/1/)):

```
<div class="row">
  <div id="a" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8">.col-xs-12 .col-sm-6 .col-md-8</div>
  <div id="b" class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
</div>
```

This will keep the first column to a width of 12 for extra small screens, and the second column will be bumped to the next row ( with a width of 6 columns ). On small screens, however, the first column will be 6 wide and the second column will be 6 wide.